# How to keep a live class on a web server

Tags: java, gwt

i am working on a GWT web application and i was wondering if there is a way to keep some classes alive on the server.

The point is that i would like to create a static class that will run on the server and manage something for me.. lets say currently logged in users.

```
public class someclass{

private static someclass instance;
private List<user> users;
private someclass(){
users = new ArrayList<user>();
}
public someclass getInstance()
{
    if (instance == null)
        instance = new someclass(); 
    return instance;
}
public addUser(user u)
{
users.add(user);
}
}
```

assume that there is no sync needed its not impotent for the question.

lets say first user logs in, and is added to the users list.
when a second user logs in. will the user list be empty? or will it have the old user as well?

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways to do this. However, a very simple way to tackle this scenario would be to use a startup servlet
In web.xml define it as follows.

```
<servlet>
 <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>TestServlet</servlet-class>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Maintain the stat in static fields of that servlet.

Comment: Sorry that i am lacking knowledge but can you point me out to something a bit more specific?. 
i'll assume that i need to create a servlet class for this.
how will i call this class's functions?
Will i need to communicate with the servelet with HTTP requests from the server. this seems a bit of a hassle

Comment: No, you do not need to use http calls. You may treat it as any other class, and have public APIs that will provide you information you want to manipulate. On server side, all your components will be on the same JVM as your server.

Answer (score 1):

While the answer of ring bearer is the most compatible (it will work even in some very old servlet containers), I think the current approach would be to register a context listener for your application. As an example, I use this in my web.xml in order to have the Quartz task scheduler available:

```
 <listener>
     <listener-class>org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
```

Your context listener must implement the `javax.servlet.ServletContextListener` interface.The servlet container will call `void contextInitialized(javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent sce)` to notify application startup. On shutdown, the servlet container will call `void contextDestroyed(javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent sce)`.

The approach with servlets is similar but your logic would be in the servlet lifecycle operations.